# Custom post type clean url

Tags: custom-post-types, urls

I'm trying to create clean url's for my custom post type, but I can't seem to figure out how to make this work.

First I followed the Wordpress codex using `publicly_queryable` and `query_var` in my public function `register_post_type`: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type

I also found this stackexchange topic, I've added the classes but I couldn't make it work:
[Clean URL permalink for custom post type](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/47890/clean-url-permalink-for-custom-post-type)

I'm using the following code to register my custom post type:

```
register_post_type('team' , array(
  'labels' => $labels,
  'public' => true,
  'has_archive' => false,
  'menu_position' => 5,
  'menu_icon' => get_stylesheet_directory_uri(). '/teamProfiles/team-icon.png',
  'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail'),
  'rewrite' => false
));
```

As mentioned above I've tried adding some values from the codex as below:

```
'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'team'),
'query_var' => 'team',
'publicly_queryable' => true
```

Maybe a note, I've build my custom post type in as a PHP class.
Hope someone can help me out.

Comment: Inside you're register_post_type you have rewrite set to false, but you say you "added" the other code as well. It looks like you have rewrite written twice. If that's not it, you should post exactly the code you are using otherwise it's hard to tell where exactly you added the additional code to and if you removed the  'rewrite' => false

Comment: Also go to => http://example.com/wp-admin/options-permalink.php and refresh/save permalink structure. After changing structure it probably didn't update.

Comment: @Candid thanks for your reply. I didn't add the rewrite code twice. I've tried updating permalink structure and that did seem to work. Thanks for that suggestion! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Generate WP](https://generatewp.com/post-type/) can help you generate a clean CPT. If this doesn't work, try the site to make sure you didn't miss anything.

---

```
// Register Custom Post Type
function custom_post_type() {

    $labels = array(
        'name'                  => _x( 'Teams', 'Post Type General Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'singular_name'         => _x( 'Team', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'menu_name'             => __( 'Team', 'text_domain' ),
        'name_admin_bar'        => __( 'Team', 'text_domain' ),
        'parent_item_colon'     => __( 'Parent Team:', 'text_domain' ),
        'all_items'             => __( 'All Teams', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_new_item'          => __( 'Add New Team', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_new'               => __( 'Add New', 'text_domain' ),
        'new_item'              => __( 'New Team', 'text_domain' ),
        'edit_item'             => __( 'Edit Team', 'text_domain' ),
        'update_item'           => __( 'Update Team', 'text_domain' ),
        'view_item'             => __( 'View Team', 'text_domain' ),
        'search_items'          => __( 'Search Team', 'text_domain' ),
        'not_found'             => __( 'Not found', 'text_domain' ),
        'not_found_in_trash'    => __( 'Not found in Trash', 'text_domain' ),
        'items_list'            => __( 'Teams list', 'text_domain' ),
        'items_list_navigation' => __( 'Teams list navigation', 'text_domain' ),
        'filter_items_list'     => __( 'Filter teams list', 'text_domain' ),
    );
    $args = array(
        'label'                 => __( 'Team', 'text_domain' ),
        'labels'                => $labels,
        'supports'              => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', ),
        'taxonomies'            => array( 'category', 'post_tag' ),
        'hierarchical'          => true,
        'public'                => true,
        'show_ui'               => true,
        'show_in_menu'          => true,
        'menu_position'         => 5,
        'menu_icon'             => get_stylesheet_directory_uri(). '/teamProfiles/team-icon.png',
        'show_in_admin_bar'     => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
        'can_export'            => true,
        'has_archive'           => false,       
        'exclude_from_search'   => false,
        'publicly_queryable'    => true,
        'capability_type'       => 'page',
    );
    register_post_type( 'team', $args );

}
add_action( 'init', 'custom_post_type', 0
```